# what is the topic-view page's name? in bbpress

Tags: bbpress

I'd like to **seperate** the "**write a New Topic**" page by a button.
but, I cannot find the "**view topic**"'s file.
where is it?
I found the write form.(form-topic.php)

Answer (score 1):

This will depend on your theme. But for the templates that come with the BBPress plug-in, the single topic template page is `singe-topic.php`. This in-turn doesn't do much, but call `content-single-topic.php`. This displays stuff like the password form for protected topics, displays topic description etc. and then loops through the replies to the topic with `loop-replies.php`.

`content-single-topic.php` includes the form to **reply** to the current topic. If you are after where the form to write a new topic is, that is in, `content-single-forum.php`, called from within `single-forum.php`.

These files will be within the plug-in's folder, unless your theme is 'bbpress-ready'. You can copy these files into your current theme and then add `add_theme_support( 'bbpress' );` into your `functions.php` to tell WordPress to look there for the templates.- Then you can edit the templates there.